# Rescaling simple join application in Flink

Tags: java, join, apache-flink, flink-streaming, scaling

Good afternoon,
I am currently working on the scalability of stateful operators in stream processing systems.

I am particularly interested in the case of the 'join' operator, for which I have implemented a fictional scenario to test its performance (especially throughput) and behavior during a rescale. However, since I am new to Flink, I don't think I have correctly implemented this generic scenario.

My current scenario involves the use of two load generators (taken from Theodolite project https://www.theodolite.rocks/theodolite-benchmarks/load-generator.html) that inject a certain number of records into two different Kafka topics. The quantity and generation time of records are parameterized.

A record consists of a triplet containing: sensor name, generation timestamp, and sensor value.

My Flink application reads records from the two topics and performs a join, using a one-second window, between messages with the same sensor name.

Here is an excerpt from my job:

```
final DataStream<ActivePowerRecord> stream1 = this.env.addSource(kafkaConsumer1).name("Source1").uid("Source1").setParallelism(1).keyBy(ActivePowerRecord::getIdentifier).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<ActivePowerRecord>forMonotonousTimestamps().withTimestampAssigner((record, timestamp) -> record.getTimestamp()));

final DataStream<ActivePowerRecord> stream2 = this.env.addSource(kafkaConsumer2).name("Source2").uid("Source2").setParallelism(1).keyBy(ActivePowerRecord::getIdentifier).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<ActivePowerRecord>forMonotonousTimestamps().withTimestampAssigner((record, timestamp) -> record.getTimestamp()));

final DataStream<String> outputStream = runWindowJoin(stream1, stream2, Integer.parseInt(windowSize));

outputStream.addSink(new DiscardingSink<>()).name("Sink").uid("4").setParallelism(1).disableChaining();
```

And here is my join function:

```
    public static DataStream<String> runWindowJoin(
            DataStream<ActivePowerRecord> tuple1,
            DataStream<ActivePowerRecord> tuple2,
            long windowSize) {
        
        return tuple1.join(tuple2)
                .where(ActivePowerRecord::getIdentifier)
                .equalTo(ActivePowerRecord::getIdentifier)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(windowSize))).trigger(EventTimeTrigger.create()).evictor(TimeEvictor.of(Time.seconds(0),true))
                .apply(new MyJoinFunction()).assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMillis(windowSize))).disableChaining();
    }"
```

I am running both load generators with the following parameters: 100000 sensors per load generator and generation rate of 1 second.
The joining window is 1 second.

With parallelism set to 1 for the join operator, everything seems to work normally as I am getting 1-to-1 joins since each sensor, for each topic, appears once within the window.
However, when I apply parallelism 2 (or more), the Cartesian product resulting from the join seems to explode the number of results and by inspecting records with print() it seems that some old records stay stuck.

As you can see in this screenshot, the delta between timestamps for a given join is way bigger than the fixed window: [Screenshot of joined records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZMS8.png)

How can I avoid the explosion of this Cartesian product? How can i keep the same "determinism" when scaling up? What am I getting really wrong here?

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: This certainly looks odd. Is it possible that 100000 was accidentally used as the window size? I think that would explain the results.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for answer. The issue was indeed related to the window size. 
The job takes the window size as a parameter, which is defined as an environment variable in the jobmanager container. 
At parallelism 1, the window size is 1000 millis as defined, but during rescale this value changes to 5000 millis. I am trying to figure out what causes this change, meanwhile hardcoding 1000 millis directly in the job seems to solve the issue.